# Jenkins error ERROR: Name must follow the pattern &#039;^[a-zA-Z0-9]+((\.|_|__|-+)[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$&#039;

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline

I am getting a jenkins fail at step Build step 'Docker Build and Publish'

The error is

```
ERROR: Name must follow the pattern &#039;^[a-zA-Z0-9]+((\.|_|__|-+)[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$&#039;
    at hudson.util.FormValidation._errorWithMarkup(FormValidation.java:268)
    at hudson.util.FormValidation.errorWithMarkup(FormValidation.java:254)
    at hudson.util.FormValidation.error(FormValidation.java:145)
    at hudson.util.FormValidation.error(FormValidation.java:170)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.credentials.ImageNameValidator.validateName(ImageNameValidator.java:289)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.credentials.ImageNameValidator.validateUserAndRepo(ImageNameValidator.java:115)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.credentials.DockerRegistryEndpoint.imageName(DockerRegistryEndpoint.java:331)
    at com.cloudbees.dockerpublish.DockerBuilder.getRepo(DockerBuilder.java:252)
    at com.cloudbees.dockerpublish.DockerBuilder$Perform.getImageTags(DockerBuilder.java:333)
    at com.cloudbees.dockerpublish.DockerBuilder$Perform.exec(DockerBuilder.java:305)
    at com.cloudbees.dockerpublish.DockerBuilder$Perform.access$100(DockerBuilder.java:291)
    at com.cloudbees.dockerpublish.DockerBuilder.perform(DockerBuilder.java:262)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:818)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:199)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:164)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:526)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1900)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:44)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:107)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:449)
```

In my jenkins build I have selected
Docker Build and Publish
and in name I have tonycav\myrepo\springboot-k8s-ingress-rest

in my DockerFile I have

```
FROM adoptopenjdk:16.0.1_9-jdk-hotspot-focal

EXPOSE 8080
ADD target/springboot-k8s-ingress-rest.jar springboot-k8s-ingress-rest.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/springboot-k8s-ingress-rest.jar"]
```

When I did a build on my jenkins it fails.
I am guessing its either it does not like tonycav\myrepo\springboot-k8s-ingress-rest as a Repository Name
Or its the credentials, but it it was credentials, I am sure the error message would be different.

When I usually push from command line I do a build then a tag then push

```
docker build -t springboot-k8s-ingress-rest .
docker push tonycav/myrepo:springboot-k8s-ingress-rest
```

I thought Jenkins would be the same but following this YouTube all I needed to do is set the Repository Name

Comment: can you please share the pipeline code that fails?

Answer (score 0):

I had the slashes the wrong way round, the correct way is

tonycav/springboot-k8s-ingress-rest